# How to sum up total rows of count? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to sum up the total rows given by count. 
My code goes like this:

```
    select count(*) from violationprofile where Year = 'Second Year' GROUP BY IDNumber;
```

but it gives me a result of

count(*)
4  ------> cause I have 4 entries of the same IDNumber
1  ------> only 1 entry of an IDNumber

I want a result of 2, because the total rows of count is only 2.
Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select count(distinct IDNumber)  
from   violationprofile 
where  Year = 'Second Year'
```

Comment: it gives me a result of zero;

Comment: Are you sure you put the same `where` clause as in your query? Because if your original query returns rows, it is impossible to get 0 with this one. If sqlfiddle.com is willing, you can see an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf0a69/1

Comment: Sorry, the first one was right. I was wrong, didn't notice I change the where clause to 'Fourth Year' which I have no entry. Lol. My fault. Thanks it worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can select the row count from your new result:

```
select count(*) from (select count(*) from violationprofile where Year = 'Second Year' GROUP BY IDNumber) as T;
```

Comment: what does "xxx" stands for?

Comment: got an error: :'(
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias